# How do I navigate to a website using a proxy?

Tags: c#, proxy, proxies

I've looked through google, and I saw things like WebRequest, WebProxy, etc. There were a lot of pages, but I don't get it. So let's say I have a TextBox with the URL in it, and another TextBox with the proxy in it. How would I make it so that I could use a proxy on the URL?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a request using the HttpWebRequest object detailed here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx

One of the properties of the HttpWebRequest object is 'Proxy':
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx

A good implementation example can be found here:
[problem using proxy with HttpWebRequest in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161608/problem-using-proxy-with-httpwebrequest-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I don't understand how to use any of those. Whenever I try to use them, it always errors, or doesn't work at all.

Comment: Why does it give you errors? Can you provide more info/details?

Comment: It usually doesn't work. I set up a simple HTML site with a site counter, and the only time it went up was when I tested it with my browser. Sometimes it tells me something about a URI, but I think I'm just using it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could use RestSharp's Rest Client (https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp) to pull data, and then render in a WebBrowser object:

```
  try {
    var response = new RestClient {
      BaseUrl = "https://theproxisright.com/",
      Proxy = new WebProxy("1.2.3.4", 8080),
      Timeout = 10000
    }.Execute(new RestRequest {
      Resource = "api/Proxy/Get?apiKey=ENTER_FREE_OR_UNLIMITED_API_KEY_HERE",
      Method = Method.GET,
    });
    if (response.ErrorException != null) {
      throw response.ErrorException;
    } else {
      Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

      var wb = new WebBrowser{ Width = 200 };
      webBrowserStack.Children.Add(wb);
      wb.NavigateToString(response.Content);
    }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  }
```